# How to remove object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, binary-search-tree

I've implemented Binary search tree in ruby, and now I need to clean whole structure but I can't find any way to do that.

```
def post_order_clean(node)
  if node.left != nil
    post_order_clean(node.left)
  end

  if node.right != nil
    post_order_clean(node.right)
  end

  node = nil
end
```

But when i do sth like that:

```
example = [4,6,9,5,7,3,1]

tree = BST::BinaryTree.new(example)
tree.clean
puts tree.root.value
```

It still prints out 4 as a root value.
How can I clean the tree with post-order traversing method?

**Edit:**

Just like @Cary Swoveland mentioned:

.. successively remove nodes (together with arcs directed to the node) that have no arcs directed to other nodes.

That's my point.

Comment: Ruby has garbage collection. If you want to clean the whole tree, just say, `tree = nil`.

Comment: @lurker Yep, but the point is i need to delete all elements one by one. That's the point of task for university

Comment: So this is a homework question, then?

Comment: `node` is a local variable, you just need to set the root to nil.

Comment: You need to drop the meaningless term "clean" and and state precisely what you want to do. For example, do you want to successively remove nodes (together with arcs directed to the node) that have no arcs directed to other nodes?

Comment: As a note, comparisons to `nil` are almost always overly specific. Unless you're concerned about values being *literally* `false`, `if node.right` should suffice.

Comment: Are you missing a `require` at the beginning of your code?

Answer (score 1):

I did this solution for insert and remove:

```
class TreeNode
    attr_accessor :val, :left, :right
    def initialize(val)
        @val = val
        @left, @right = nil, nil
    end

    def insert(v)
        side = (v <= val ? :left : :right)

        if send(side)
            send(side).insert(v)
        else
            send("#{side}=", TreeNode.new(v))
        end
    end

    def delete(v)
        if v < val
            self.left = self.left ? self.left.delete(v) : nil
        elsif v > val
            self.right = self.right ? self.right.delete(v) : nil
        else
            if self.left.nil?
                return self.right
            elsif self.right.nil?
                return self.left
            end

            min = self.right
            min = min.left while !min.left.nil?

            self.val = min.val
            self.right = self.right.delete(self.val)
        end
        self
    end
end
```